# Can reactJS render <xsl:value-of/> xslt tags?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xslt

I'm a new reactJS dev, and i'm tryin to render a xslt tag with render method. Anyone can help me?

```
import React from 'react';

class Titulo extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <xsl:value-of select="$website-name"/>
        );
    }
}

export default Titulo;
```

Comment: Write your attempt (your code ) here .. We will rely on it to analyze your issue , then, give you solution accordingly .

Comment: Are you using react 16 ?

Comment: The code was pasted above

Comment: Are you using react 16 ?

Comment: ok you will see my answer after a while

Comment: I'm using react 16.1

Comment: We are done. See my answer!

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to render it as string .. And since you are using React 16, you don't need to wrap this string with a tag and the `render` method can render a [string](https://gist.github.com/ahmedtehseen/21351c45c0a719372bad5c8f548d508f#file-fragmentstring-js) .

```
import React from 'react';

class Titulo extends React.Component{

    render(){
      return `<xsl:value-of select="$website-name"/>`
    }
}

export default Titulo;
```

Before React 16, you need to render as following :

```
import React from 'react';

class Titulo extends React.Component{

    render(){
      return <div>{`<xsl:value-of select="$website-name"/>`}</div>
    }
}

export default Titulo;
```

Comment: When i render it as a string, i get the return exactly as a tag <xsl:value-of select="$website-name"/>, when i want to get a value from xml  through xslt

Comment: It's still rendering <xsl:value-of select="$website-name"> as a full string

Comment: If you expect this answer to compile xsl , I am sorry, it will not. Indeed, it is an rendering of xml statically as you requested. If you want something else, you need to be more clear when writing your question.

Comment: I would like to know how to do jsx execute tags like <xsl: value-of select = "$ website-name" />

Answer (score 0):

Look into the npm package 'xsl-awesome'. You might, and I say might, find your answer there.